# How to use ifelse row-wise in R data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to create a new column in an `R` `data.table` that is based on an `ifelse()` comparison of different columns. However, I'd like the `ifelse` statement to be applied row-wise. I've tried using the group `by` functionality of `data.table`, but it seems to apply the `test` condition of the `ifelse` row-wise but evaluate `yes` condition across *all values in the column* instead of using the `by` condition to do it *row-wise*. Below is an example and some of the solutions that I've tried.

I have an `R` `data.table` like this:

```
> set.seed(45)
> DT <- data.table(date = c(rep("2018-01-01", 3), rep("2018-01-02", 3), rep("2018-01-03", 3)), 
+                  id = rep(letters[1:3], 3), 
+                  v1 = sample(x = -20:20, size = 9), 
+                  v2 = sample(x = -20:20, size = 9))
> str(DT)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  9 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ date: chr  "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-02" ...
 $ id  : chr  "a" "b" "c" "a" ...
 $ v1  : int  5 -8 -11 -6 -7 -10 -13 -2 -14
 $ v2  : int  -20 -6 14 -9 -3 -5 19 12 -16
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
> DT
         date id  v1  v2
1: 2018-01-01  a   5 -20
2: 2018-01-01  b  -8  -6
3: 2018-01-01  c -11  14
4: 2018-01-02  a  -6  -9
5: 2018-01-02  b  -7  -3
6: 2018-01-02  c -10  -5
7: 2018-01-03  a -13  19
8: 2018-01-03  b  -2  12
9: 2018-01-03  c -14 -16
```

I want the following output:

```
> DT_out
         date id  v1  v2  c
1: 2018-01-01  a   5 -20  0
2: 2018-01-01  b  -8  -6  0
3: 2018-01-01  c -11  14 11
4: 2018-01-02  a  -6  -9  0
5: 2018-01-02  b  -7  -3  0
6: 2018-01-02  c -10  -5  0
7: 2018-01-03  a -13  19 13
8: 2018-01-03  b  -2  12  2
9: 2018-01-03  c -14 -16  0
```

**Solutions I've tried:**

**Attempt #1)** No error, but evaluates the `min` across all values in both `v1` and `v2`. This behavior is to be expected; though, it's odd to me that it evaluates the `test` condition on a row-wise basis even without a `key` set or `by` stated:

```
> DT[, c := ifelse(v1 < 0 & v2 > 0, min(-v1, v2), 0)]
> DT
         date id  v1  v2   c
1: 2018-01-01  a   5 -20   0
2: 2018-01-01  b  -8  -6   0
3: 2018-01-01  c -11  14 -20
4: 2018-01-02  a  -6  -9   0
5: 2018-01-02  b  -7  -3   0
6: 2018-01-02  c -10  -5   0
7: 2018-01-03  a -13  19 -20
8: 2018-01-03  b  -2  12 -20
9: 2018-01-03  c -14 -16   0
```

**Attempt #2)** When I set the `key` and use the `by` condition, nothing changes but I receive an error message.

```
> setkey(DT, date, id)
> DT[, c := ifelse(v1 < 0 & v2 > 0, min(-v1, v2), 0), by = list(date, id)]
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(c, ifelse(v1 < 0 & v2 > 0, min(-v1,  : 
  Type of RHS ('integer') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)
> DT
         date id  v1  v2   c
1: 2018-01-01  a   5 -20   0
2: 2018-01-01  b  -8  -6   0
3: 2018-01-01  c -11  14 -20
4: 2018-01-02  a  -6  -9   0
5: 2018-01-02  b  -7  -3   0
6: 2018-01-02  c -10  -5   0
7: 2018-01-03  a -13  19 -20
8: 2018-01-03  b  -2  12 -20
9: 2018-01-03  c -14 -16   0
```

Since the combination of `date` and `id` is unique for each row, it's all the more difficult for me to understand why this isn't being evaluated for each `group`, which is, in this case, each row.

Perhaps I need to use `.SDcols = .(date, id)` and `.SD` in the `ifelse`, but I don't know how to use the `.SD` in the `ifelse`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `pmin` instead of `min`:

```
DT[, c := ifelse(v1 < 0 & v2 > 0, pmin(-v1, v2), 0)]

> DT
         date id  v1  v2  c
1: 2018-01-01  a   5 -20  0
2: 2018-01-01  b  -8  -6  0
3: 2018-01-01  c -11  14 11
4: 2018-01-02  a  -6  -9  0
5: 2018-01-02  b  -7  -3  0
6: 2018-01-02  c -10  -5  0
7: 2018-01-03  a -13  19 13
8: 2018-01-03  b  -2  12  2
9: 2018-01-03  c -14 -16  0

# see also:
?pmin
```

> pmax*() and pmin*() take one or more vectors as arguments, recycle them to common length and return a single vector giving the ‘parallel’
>   maxima (or minima) of the argument vectors.

[added later]

Your original code works as well, if you first change the column types:

```
  DT[, v1:= as.numeric(v1)]   # was integer, converting to 'double'
  DT[, v2:= as.numeric(v2)]   # ---,,---
  DT[, c := ifelse(v1 < 0 & v2 > 0, min(-v1, v2), 0), by = list(date, id)]
```

As far as I understand, the data.table philosophy is not to let R change the column types "implicitly" but that the type would stay until changed explicitly.

The manual says:

> Unlike <- for data.frame, the (potentially large) LHS is not coerced to match the type of the (often
>   small) RHS. Instead the RHS is coerced to match the type of the LHS, if necessary. Where this
>   involves double precision values being coerced to an integer column, a warning is given (whether
>   or not fractional data is truncated). The motivation for this is efficiency. It is best to get the column
>   types correct up front and stick to them. Changing a column type is possible but deliberately harder:
>   provide a whole column as the RHS. This RHS is then plonked into that column slot and we call this
>   plonk syntax, or replace column syntax if you prefer. By needing to construct a full length vector of
>   a new type, you as the user are more aware of what is happening, and it’s clearer to readers of your
>   code that you really do intend to change the column type.

So far so good. But of course, the original error message is confusing.

```
 # To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases.
```

"For the fastest cases?". This must be one of the fastest cases as the data set is microscopically tiny, and I bet nobody would notice the impact of performance in this case if `data.table` would allow implicit type conversions. So the primary motivation for this error message seems to be that the package author wants to enforce what he believes to be good practice.

This will also work (without type conversions):

```
 DT[, c := ifelse(v1 < 0 & v2 > 0, as.numeric(min(-v1, v2)), 0), by = list(date, id)]  # 1
```

or alternatively:

```
 DT[, c := ifelse(v1 < 0 & v2 > 0, min(-v1, v2), 0L), by = list(date, id)] # 2
```

But you cannot run the last two rows -- #1 and #2 -- one after another, the `c` column has to be deleted first. `DT$c` will be numeric in the first case and integer in second.

#### a few additional experiments

```
DT[, c:= NULL] 
DT[, c := ifelse(v1 < 0, v1, 0), by = list(date, id)] 
# error but DT$c col created with first element as NA
# the condition was FALSE for the first element, so numeric 0 became the first element of c
# ... but the next element would be integer, hence the error
DT$c # [1]  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
DT[, c:= NULL] 
DT[, c := ifelse(v1 > 0, v1, 0), by = list(date, id)]
# error; DT$c column is integer, with 5 as first element and the rest as NA 
DT$c # [1]  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
DT[, c:= NULL] 
DT[, c := ifelse(v1 < 0, as.numeric(v1), 0), by = list(date, id)] 
# works without error but results in numeric DT$c
is.numeric(DT$c) # TRUE
DT[, c := ifelse(v1 < 0, v1, 0L), by = list(date, id)]
# type error, DT$c was numeric and we are trying to add an integer column
DT[, c:= NULL] # deleting the c column again
DT[, c := ifelse(v1 < 0, v1, 0L), by = list(date, id)]
# no error now
is.integer(DT$c) # TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I’m still not totally clear what the data.table error means that pops up on my second attempt. But, your solution works so that is all that matters.

Comment: I added something on it to the answer (would have been too long for a comment)

Comment: Thanks for adding to the answer, very helpful! Though, it's still a bit unclear to me. Perhaps I should make the following a separate question? Let me know, and I will. I want to create an `integer` column `c` by using two `integer` columns `v1` and `v2`, so why are there any data coercion issues? Everything involved is an `integer`. I looked at the documentation of `min`/`max` it does not look like either automatically return a `numeric` when supplied with `integers` so doesn't look that is coercing any data.

Comment: I didn't understand it either ... but then experimented a bit with it.  When using `:=`, it matters a lot whether the column you're assigning to already exists or not. So using `0L` instead of `0` as a second part of `ifelse` helps as well. (Actually, that was the original source of the problem. `0` is numeric, but your `v1` and `v2` are integer.) What I find a bit problematic are the cases above when a variable is created with `:=` but only partially filled with data.

Comment: Ah, brilliant. I'm not good at much in R (or very much else for that matter), but generally I'm pretty good about using `L` to denote an integer -- should have realized that. Thanks for the responsiveness!